# awk åäö umlaut-chars has length of 2

Tags: string, macos, awk, diacritics

I'm using awk (mac os x) to print only lines that are n characters and longer.

If I try it on a text file (strings.txt) that looks like this:

```
four
foo
bar
föö
bår
fo
ba
fö
bå
```

And I run this awk script:

```
awk ' { if( length($0) >= 3 ) print $0 } ' <strings.txt
```

The output is:

```
four
foo
bar
föö
bår
fö
bå
```

(The last two lines should not have been printed). It seems like words that contain umlaut-characters (å, ä, ö...) count as two characters.

(The input file is saved in UTF8 format.)

Comment: So the question is then: is awk (length in particular) Unicode-aware?

Answer (score 4):

**BSD `awk` (a.k.a BWK `awk`), as preinstalled on macOS** (still true as of macOS 10.13), is - sadly - **NOT Unicode-aware.**

Your **choices** are:

- **IF** you know that the **characters involved fit into a single-byte encoding** such as ISO-8859-1, you can **use `iconv`** as follows:

  ```
  iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO-8859-1 file | awk 'length >= 3' | iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8
  ```
- **Install a *different `awk` implementation*** that *is* Unicode-aware, such as `gawk` (GNU Awk) or `mawk`; e.g., via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh):

  - `brew info gawk`
  - `brew info mawk`
- Use a ***different preinstalled tool* that *is* Unicode-aware**, such as `sed`:

  ```
  sed -n '/^.\{3,\}/p' file
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting your locale:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk 'length >= 3' infile
```

Change en_US.UTF-8 to your correct locale.

Comment: i am new to this, please bear with me. How do i set locale before running awk again? I tried "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8" but it doesn't work...

Comment: You should use either: `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk ...` or `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; awk ...`.

Comment: I used the first option

    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk....

However, my script wasn't able to find unicode string txt, say the string "Name"...dont know how to fix this...

Comment: In my replies I was referring to GNU awk, which awk implementation are you using?

Comment: I have resolved the problem. The issue was in the file, it was in UTF16 not UTF8. the gawk i am using is 4.0.0. Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Comment: I had the same problem on Mac OS (Lion) and can confirm that the LC_ALL.. trick works, but I had to use GNU awk (4.0.0). Easily installed with homebrew (brew install gawk).

Comment: @Odinodin: Switching to `gawk` by itself is sufficient - no need for `LC_ALL` trickery, as long as your locale is UTF8-based (which it should be on OSX).

Comment: BSD `awk` - the one that comes with OS X - is, sadly, not Unicode-aware, so this solution won't work, no matter what you set `LC_ALL` or `LANG` to.

Answer (score 0):

if you're absolutely sure that your input is already 100% "well-formed" UTF8 texts, then you can simply count length with this short snippet, with ***non***-unicode aware versions of awk :

```
`mawk/mawk2/nawk/gawk -b 'BEGIN { FS = "^$" 
  
     } { bytes += length($0) 
         gsub(/[\200-\301\365-\377]+/,"") 

           # if u know it's well-formed
           # then once you clean out all continuation 
           # bytes, you're only left with ASCII and 
           # the multi-byte leading bytes of \xC2-\xF4

           chars += length($0) 
     } END { 
            printf("rows       = %\047.f | "\
                   "UTF8 chars = %\047.f | "\
                   "bytes      = %\047.f\n",\
                    NR, \
                    NR+chars,\
                    NR+bytes) }'  # remove the \047 for mawk2
```

and don't worry about locale settings at it. as long as you're in gawk byte mode, or any of the non-unicode aware variants, this works just fine.

This shall properly count any single point spec'ed in Unicode 13.

- ps : having UTF16 surrogate pairs doesn't necessarily constitute "well-formed" UTF8 per se.

performance wise, it beats gnu-wc binary rather handily - about +67% faster on multi-byte heavy input, some +134% on multi-byte lighter input   :

> first file

time pvE0 < "${m3t}" | mawk2 'BEGIN { FS = "^$" …. }

```
  in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:16 [ 114MiB/s] [ 114MiB/s] [============================>] 100%
```

rows       = 12494275. | UTF8 chars = 1285316715. | bytes      = 1983544693.

pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}"  0.07s user 0.78s system 5% cpu **16.575** total

time pvE0 < "${m3t}" |  gwc -lcm
in0: 1.85GiB 0:00:27 [68.0MiB/s] [68.0MiB/s] [============================>] 100%
12494275 1285316715 1983544693
pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3t}"  0.07s user 0.80s system 3% cpu **27.838** total

> second file

```
  in0:  988MiB 0:00:03 [ 316MiB/s] [ 316MiB/s] [============================>] 100%
```

rows       = 5983333. | UTF8 chars = 969069988. | bytes      = 1036334374.

pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3s}"  0.04s user 0.60s system 20% cpu **3.177** total

time pvE0 < "${m3s}" | gwc -lcm
in0:  988MiB 0:00:07 [ 135MiB/s] [ 135MiB/s] [============================>] 100%
5983333 969069988 1036334374
pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3s}"  0.04s user 0.39s system 5% cpu **7.318** total

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$  echo "four
foo
bar
föö
bår
fo
ba
fö
bå
"|awk ' {x=$0;gsub(/./,"x",x); if( length(x) >= 3 ) print $0 } '
```

**output**

```
four
foo
bar
föö
bår
```

Comment: This is essentially a no-op and will not solve the problem - either your `awk` is Unicode-aware, or it's not. If `.` in a regex context matches a non-ASCII char, the implication is that `length` will also recognize it as a single char, and there's no point in replacing it.